# I'm trying to identify this succulent

Tags: identification

Looks like Hens & Chicks on steroids.

[image: mystery plant]

I am in Baja California near Ensenada.

Comment: If you can snag a tiny rosette they are very easy to root and grow like mad with sun and water. It is a beautiful plant, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Its a type of Aeonium.  Maybe Aeonium canariense.  There are a lot of hybrids of aeonium so it might be difficult to pin it down exactly.  Canariense's leaves get tinged with red in bright sunlight.

Comment: It is an aeonium, I have one that is similar.

Comment: It must be. I got one too.